# What path (programming language, courses) should I take inorder to become a network/ security developer. (Not network configuration)?

Tags: network, software

I would want to work in network and network security field as a developer(programmer),developing network products(not network/network product configuration) ultimately to get into network security product development and research. I am going to pursue masters in CS specialising in Network/Security

Note : If this is opinion based, i would like to know different opinions. Answers from different perspective wont harm.

Comment: This is a very opinion based question, so I'll add what I know as a comment. I know of a company developing security tools. Backend is done in C/C++, fancy interface in Java. I'm also reading a book teaching python for pen-testing since it's a very neat, clean and powerful scripting language. So in the end it depends what you want to do. But learning any of these languages is never wasted.

Comment: If this helps, I applied for a forensic software development internship before, and I had to write many C programs, and learn/understand lower level concepts

Comment: If you want to go into network security and pen testing I would go for Python.  It is a solid scripting language with a lot of robust network libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There's no straight way to develop a product. It is non-trivial thing. I'd start from the top with the learning of the networking which is basically switching, routing, load-balancing, proxying, fail-overing, firewalling (so that would be Computer Network Course), and then I'd proceed to enterprise grade programming language which aids in things like Big Data, network capture and so on.

Network Course is non-trivial but very well structured so it's easy to complete one. It takes at least a year to learn what can be done with network switch alone. However, to invent any software takes another year. And then implementing the first version may take another year. That's how the R&D works.

On the other side, I'd take course in cryptography but I'd look also on concepts like SSO, network monitoring, orchestrating. It's not as heavy as big-data but very helpful and that's were new products are heading

There's also the secret sauce of next-generation products which is Machine Learning.

Regarding network products like switches and routers, it's usually more than a switch - it's whole ecosystem of software, which includes e.g. VHDL, Verilog for hardware and C for software, which is embedded software.

You can check for job posting to find out what specific company (e.g. the one in your country or city) is using.

You can also have a look on [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) IDE.

See here: [Hardware Description Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language)

However, to produce the switch or security gateway, there's a lot bigger ecosystem of things like simulation, prototyping. You can still go for HDLs if you want to develop next generation networking products.

There's also Robotics, real-time network communication, network virtualization, for each of these, different programming language is used while HDLs are the Hardware Description Languages for programming the hardware itself. There's still software running on it as well (like C or Java, depends on the vendor).

As you have some experience with Web Development you would already know APIs and things related to the web which is better than good start.

If you intend developing products and platforms, you should decide on your product architecture and technology, so you can choose whatever suits you best. Plus, you should choose something which is more decent regarding syntax and has extensive libraries for the functionality you need, for example:

- Java and Scala for high performance, high scalability enterprise applications, mainly if it's going to be huge platform. The build-in language safety and threading makes it very attractive and indeed very popular. Huge number of professional grade libraries. There's everything - profilers, debuggers, editors and it's whole load of them. JRE is the #1 runtime today.
- C is universal language and anything can be done and there's also huge number of libraries. If you look into kernel hacking or other linux based development, that's the way to go. It is useful to know for debugging common issues, exploits, reporting issues and so on.
- C++ similarly to C, if used well can do a lot for you, whatever it's cross-platform app in QT, GTK, DirectX, OpenGL, server or engine. There's are many paid libraries to do many things, however not every library is available in C++ nor it's always free. However, for things like web browser hacking, games hacking, C++ knowledge is very useful.
- Python is general scripting language. It has excellent standard library which is very important, has built-in safety and it's also very popular. There's good ecosystem supporting it as good as in Java (from developer perspective, there are libraries, editors, visual debuggers). I said almost, but it's the only thing getting close. It's ideal for development of command-line utilities. It is extensively used in many fields so there are many experimental libraries not available in other languages.
- C# is what powers Windows but regarding cross-platform support it is currently in flux, the new .NET Core has small number of issues regarding importing existing libraries, and Mono is another open sourced runtime. It's good for ASP.NET. The syntax and language design is superior. There's plenty of libraries for Windows. It can be used for anything like command-line utilities, GUI applications and IIS powered websites.
- PHP is good for prototyping, scripting and testing and obviously developing web pages. It builds on any server like Python. Since it was designed and optimized for web, it is very compact and very fast and can be used for many other things. It's one of the most clever languages out there. There's little bloat in everything you do.
- Javascript is the only choice (along with Typestript) for building client-side applications running in web browser. It can be also used for server-side applications, however, there are not as many libraries as in Java, Python and has bigger limitations than Python. However, it is fast and compact. Syntax is the most horrible one, but there's no alternative for web browsers. It is very quickly evolving. There's new JS framework every hour.
- What Perl is everyone knows. If you want to develop server-side daemon it can do the job, however, you won't have editor auto-suggestions like with Java, but Linux packaging and Docker can help you dealing with dependencies when deploying it to cloud. There's more than one library to do anything, even most exotic things. It is closely tied to the OS just like Python.
- Ruby is used for generation of web pages. Otherwise there's little libraries yet but it's slowly happening. But before it reaches the level of Python it may take long time. If you are interested in porting, integrating and creating libraries that's something interesting. Also there's relatively poor editor support. Linux packages and Docker can help you dealing with dependencies.

And finally:

- Swift is the next-generation compiled language which has additional safety compared to C. It's not only that, there's the whole layer of libraries with it. I am currently onto it myself so I can't tell much yet how it works on Linux, but so far so cool.
- Groovy is next-generation language running on JRE. With Grails you can create powerful enterprise applications with little code and you can use any Java library. It is usable and enterprise ready.
- Scala is Java alternative, can use Java libraries, you can also create enterprise applications (Play framework), however with being enterprise ready there are few glitches you might not encounter if you are not in enterprise environment, in particular, they do not support HTTPS for their downloads which basically is big pain if you have to use it, and it's problem for many.

And finally:

- Java, Scala, Static Groovy, C# are for high performance, multi-threaded application servers which can do more than serving web pages - like listening on sockets, schedule jobs, process data and so on with high performance and safety. Todays Java is really nice. Static typing is important if you want performance and safety, so anything where multiple clients are connecting or you process a lot of data like real-time systems. Java can handle it well today.
- Use C, C++ only when you have to, including real-time systems which is must-have in networking.
- Use HDLs for Hardware Development
- Use dynamic languages for scripting, web pages for managed hosting. You can use Python for almost everything, but look at Java as well.

ps. I don't mention any GUIs - in fact, it's real hell. I do myself HTML5. Sometimes I build it with embedded browser engine. Sometimes C++ / QT, WinRT etc. Look out for the various widget libraries etc.

You will need also to seriously consider database engines. Historically, all database engines were SQLs - MariaDB, Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Server. These are good for generic engines like CRUD, for security you can look at MongoDB, Cassandra, Neo4j, Redis, and also Hadoop and things like Sping Framework, Apache Spark and so on. For embedded devices it's SQL Lite, but many newer embedded devices mainly rely on the real-time, super highly available databases, which are usually specialized for the job any sometimes not free.

Comment: Thanks for the information provided, but i would appreciate if the answer was more focused towards suggesting languages like java socket programming , python scripting etc. What i want to know is how do i get into network/security product development industry. I already have years of experience in developing web applications.

Comment: OK, I leave the reply as it's ok as for 2016 and may be helpful. Regarding IT Security products, it's just product as any other product. I'd consider big data (java and databases), picture recognition (python), enterprise applications (java), OS scripting (python). and the databases. If you look into hardware products, then it's the same, and seriously, I'd consider using Swift! You might get investment for this.

Comment: And also you may think what security product you'd like to do for example. It could be something innovative, I've done few of these and I used mainly Java, but now I am looking at Python and Swift as in Python I have libraries and I have other benefits in Swift.

Comment: Security products like firewall, implementation/development of HTTPS protocols.These i mentioned in general, somewhere in this line.

Comment: Network products- The routing logic implemented in routers, packet switching implementation etc.